# Is there a programmatic Linux/Unix/Mac way to obtain the dimensions of a JPEG?

Tags: linux, mac, unix, images, jpeg

```
Inner Sanctum ~/mirror/images $ file wardrobe_square_90.gif
wardrobe_square_90.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 90 x 90
Inner Sanctum ~/mirror/images $ file wardrobe_square_90.jpg
wardrobe_square_90.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
Inner Sanctum ~/mirror/images $ file wardrobe_square_90.png
wardrobe_square_90.png: PNG image data, 90 x 90, 8-bit/color RGB, interlaced
```

Calling file on some formats gets the images' dimensions, but not JPEG.

I see a way to use ImageMagick to call convert to make a PNG from the JPEG or whatnot, but that has a mild code smell.

Is there a good way to query a JPEG's dimensions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick has `identify` which "describes  the  format  and characteristics of one or more image files."

```
$ identify bild.jpg 
bild.jpg JPEG 480x640 480x640+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 57.2KiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

As with most things UNIX, there are a number of ways to do the same thing.

NetPBM utilities provides a utility `pnmfile` which, when combined with `djpeg`, gives file dimensions for JPEG files:

```
% djpeg default_wallpaper.jpg | pnmfile -
-:      PPM raw, 1920 by 1280  maxval 255
```

`djpeg` can be found in many JPEG packages, as can the NetPBM utilities.  On Centos/RHEL for example the packages are available from the base repository as:
`netpbm-progs` and `libjpeg-turbo`